# Using pointer and reference as return type in same function

Tags: c++

So I was looking at some code and I came across this.

```
class Data{
 private:
  int data;
  Data* next;
 public:
   Data(int d=0): data(d), next(NULL) {}
   void SetData(int d) { data = d;}
   int  GetData() { return data; }
   Data*& GetNext() { return next; }
 }
```

The `GetNext()` return type is both the reference and pointer as return type. What does this mean?

Comment: It is a reference to a pointer of type `Data`. So it behaves like a pointer but if you change its value you will also change the original pointer.

Comment: The return type of the `GetNext` is a reference to pointer. Not really different from returning `int&` - you wouldn't say the function returns both `int` and a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X *` is a pointer to a `X`.

`T &` is a reference to a `T`. If `T` happens to be a pointer type, then it is a reference to a pointer: `X* &` is a reference to a `X*`.

As such, `Data*&` is a reference to a pointer to a `Data`.

Answer (score 2):

The value returned from `GetNext()` is a reference to a pointer to `Data`. This means it acts just like a pointer but if you change the value it will change the original object.

```
int main()
{
     Data*   d1 = new Data(1);
     std::cout << d1->GetData() << " : " << d1->GetNext()   // prints null;
               << "\n";

     d1->getNext() = new Data(2);   // Modify the value.

     std::cout << d1->GetData() << " : " << d1->GetNext()   // Does not print null
               << " -> " 
               <<  d1->GetNext()->GetData() << " : " << d1->GetNext()->GetNext()
               << "\n";
}
```